# Post variable on hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a drop down list in my `php` page that is hyperlinked to different pages contained on different servers; `html`, `asp.net` pages etc.

The URL of these pages do not contain the same domain name as the drop down list. Therefore, in order to prevent the user from directly entering the URL in the address bar, I would like to post a variable when the user clicks an item in the list.

This variable will be sent along the hyperlinked URL. The asp.net page will check whether the variable is received along with the request, if yes the page will load otherwise the asp.net page will redirect the user to my home page.

My question: What is the process of posting a variable? Where in the hyperlink does this variable need to be included. I am totally lost.

EDIT: I tried to post through `form.submit`

```
<li><form id="sampleForm" name="sampleForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" value="">
<a onclick="setValue();">ELMSTest</a>
</form></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setValue(){
    document.sampleForm.total.value = 100;
    document.forms["sampleForm"].submit();
}
</script>
```

I dont know how to proceed from here.

Comment: If you want to POST (= HTTP POST METHOD), you will need either a form using this method, or an AJAX POST call. I must admit I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: Your form misses an `action`attribute indicating to where (=URL) you want to POST. besides this and if we don't talk about the inline javascript, from where I see it this code should work.

Comment: In the `action` I will make a call to a php file `test.php`. However, what needs to go in this file? Do I need to make call to the hyperlinked like `header('Location: www.abc.com/form.asp');`. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this as you are using the POST action. Which you are by virtue of having `method="post" on your  tag.

```
`<form id="sampleForm" name="sampleForm" method="post">`
```

Because you have no `action="script.php"` it will send your inputs to the script that generated this page and run it again. So assuming this is called `script.php`...

In the PHP code of script.php the data will be delivered to you in the $_POST array.

```
<?php

    if ( isset($_POST['total'] && $_POST['total'] == 1 ) {
        // I have a foo variable with the value of one. So do something with it.
    }
```

If you want to use the get action or add variables to a hyperlink as:

```
www.domain.net/script.php?foo=1&bar=2
```

The `?` starts the list of variables, the `querystring` and each variable is seperated by an `&` if you want to pass more than one.

And of course the variables are passed in the $_GET array to your PHP code.

```
<?php

    if ( isset($_GET['foo'] && $_GET['foo'] == 1 ) {
        // I have a foo variable with the value of one. So do something with it.
    }

    if ( isset($_GET['bar'] && $_GET['bar'] == 2 ) {
        // I have a bar variable with the value of two. So do something with it.
    }
```

Comment: If I add `www.domain.net/script.php?foo=1&bar=2` to the hyperlink, is that all required? I did not understand the `GET` php script. Where does this go?

Comment: Ignore it for now, as you are using POST. But if you had for example a picture on the page and you wanted the user sent to another page if they clicked on it, you would wrap the <img> tag in an anchor `<a>` tag and the `href` of the anchor tag could look like `www.domain.net/script.php?foo=1&bar=2`

Comment: Also you dont need to submit the form with javascript, all you need to do is add a submit button inside your `<form></form> tags `<input type=submit" name="something" value"Go For it">` When the user clicks the button the form is submitted